# gradle depedencies and cache

Tags: java, gradle

I have a simple testing-purpose gradle project, which I want to scan its dependencies using `gradle dependencies` command.  Before I do so I want to make sure that the project's dependencies are actually found in the gradle's cache (`.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2/1`). To do so I run the `gradle assemble` command to download the missing dependencies before scanning.

I found out that its working only if the project has a `src/main/java` folder with a Java file inside it (even if that Java file is completely empty).

Is this a valid workaround? Is there any better solution to guarantee the dependencies are found in the cache folder before scanning them?

Comment: Is there some reason you have a gradle project with dependencies but you _don't_ have any source files?

Comment: @tddmonkey for example to write deployment scripts for externally hosted non-jar dependencies. Those would normally be defined via an extra `configuration` with tasks written to perform some operations with files of those `configurations`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason that you want to do that?

`assemble` task assemble your source files, if there is nothing to assemble the task is not needed to run. The fact you are adding the java file to src its a **hack** to run this task and its children tasks.

Depending on what you want to achieve there are few ways to 'scan' dependencies.

For more info you can visit https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies

---

Aditionally:

There is a netflix plugin that I believe can scan through your gradle scripts a check unused dependencies https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin

There is a plugin that can scan the vulnerabilities of used dependencies etc https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-gradle/